# Find the overridden parameters of a hydra config object

Tags: fb-hydra

If I set up my hydra config.yaml file with a parameter `param1: 12` and then override it through the command line e.g

```
python run.py param1==42
```

And `run.py` is :

```
@hydra.main(version_base=None, config_path=".", config_name='config.yaml')
def main(cfg) :
   ...
```

Is there a way to see which parameters were overridden this way ? For example something like `cfg.overrides() -> dict` ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This is available in the HydraConfig singleton.
You can also inspect that object from the command line with the flag `--cfg hydra`.

```py
import hydra
from hydra.core.hydra_config import HydraConfig


@hydra.main(version_base=None, config_path="conf", config_name="cfg")
def main(cfg):
    print(HydraConfig.get().overrides.task)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```